# Replace virtual functions on templates

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I'm trying to replace virtual functions on templates:

```
struct Derived1;
struct Derived2;

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    void f();
};

template<>
void Base::f<Derived1>(){std::cout<<"Derived1\n";}

template<>
void Base::f<Derived2>(){std::cout<<"Derived2\n";}


struct Derived1 : public Base {};
struct Derived2 : public Base {};
```

It works until we create a container of pointers:

```
std::vector<Base*> vec;//doesn't work - needs explicit parameter for Base
vec.push_back(new Derived1);
vec[0]->f();//Call f() from Derived1
```

Is it possible to get rid of the "virtuality" in this case?

Comment: Take a look into CRTP. I've only ever seen it a bit differently than that.

Comment: There's no `virtual` keyword in there at all. Template specialization is not like `virtual`.

The question is very unclear because you ask to get *rid* of the virtuality, but there isn't any in the first place.

Comment: `Base::f()` specialization doesn't look right either. Member function `Base::f` isn't a template function, yet your definition is specializing for `Base::f<Derived1>` which doesn't make sense at all. Did you test compile this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`virtual` function dispatch can determine the runtime dynamic type of an object before selecting which function to call. Templates cannot do that, because they are all resolved at compile time. If you have a `base *`, no template will help recall what derived type it was initialized from.

Slightly off topic, function template specialization is rarely a good idea. Overloads are more flexible because the compiler has a mechanism to select an overload which best fits the particular function call. Explicit specializations do not create overloads, but only alter the behavior of a pre-existing general template. They are the least flexible way to ask for a dispatch.